# Algorithm for a poker-style scoring system

Tags: php

What I need is to create five random integer (say `rand(1,5)`). Then, I generate a score based on these numbers. For instance, if I get a result of `1,2,3,4,5` then that would equal a zero score, but if I got `1,1,3,4,5` that would be 1 as we have a pair. Similar to a poker kind of scoring, so five of the same number would be a "full house" thus resulting in the highest score.

How would I go about the scoring system, even if it is just the mathematical equation?

More detail:

1-5 will hold separate images and then will be fought against "The House" which will have identical code to the user to determine the winner. Here's some example draws and the score they would receive:

```
1,2,3,4,5 = score 0
1,1,2,3,4 = score 1 (1 pair)
1,1,2,2,4 = score 2 (2 pair)
1,1,1,3,4 = score 3 (3 of a kind)
1,1,1,1,5 = score 4 (4 of a kind)
1,1,1,3,3 = score 5 (full house)
1,1,1,1,1 = score 6 (5 of a kind)
```

The combination of numbers is irreverent if they score 6 and the house scores 6, it's a tie.

```
    if (isset($_POST['play'])) {
    $rand1 = rand(1, 5);
    $rand2 = rand(1, 5);
    $rand3 = rand(1, 5);
    $rand4 = rand(1, 5);
    $rand5 = rand(1, 5);
    if ($_POST['bet'] <= $user_data['coins']) {
        if ($_POST['bet'] < 999999999) {
            if ($_POST['bet'] > 0.99) {
                if ($user_data['coins'] >= 1) {
                    $array = array($rand1,$rand2,$rand3,$rand4,$rand5);
                    print_r(array_count_values($array));
                    echo $rand1.', '.$rand2.', '.$rand3.', '.$rand4.', '.$rand5;

                    Array( // Here I don't understand
                    1 => 3,//
                    2 => 1,//
                    3 => 1 //
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

This outputs ; Array ( [5] => 2 [4] => 2 [1] => 1 ) 5, 5, 4, 4, 1

Comment: Can you show what code you've written so far to solve the problem?  Also, can you be more specific about the scoring rules?  Does `1 1 1 1 1` score the same as `5 5 5 5 5`?

Comment: @mikejones the op is clearly not using Java, since the question is tagged with `php` and `mysql`, although I fail to see the connection with the latter.

Comment: @Havelock, I was browsing the Java section to find this question... so be cool.

Comment: How are you generating your random int that can also affect the result

Comment: Basically 1,1,1,1,1 would be == 5,5,5,5,5 in points, Think of it that each number between 1-5 would have an independent image ascociated to each number, the more times your images match out of 5 would indicate a higher score, all images being different would result in a lower score.

Comment: Yes please to seeing your code - Stack Overflow readers like to see some prior effort `:)`

Comment: I'll add in what I've got and it's output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the approach I would consider, building on @Lele's answer. Warning: this is a bit confusing, so sit down with a cup of tea for this one.

- Build a set of five buckets, [1] to [5], and scan a player's numbers, so that the count for each number is stored in the corresponding bucket
- Then count the numbers you are left with into a new bucket system, with each position representing the number of counts you have for something.

So, if your score is this:

```
1 1 2 2 4
```

Then your first buckets are:

```
2 2 0 1 0
```

That's because you have two ones, two twos, and one four. And your second buckets are:

```
1 2 0 0 0
```

That's because you have two two-counts, and one one-count. Here, you disregard the first position (since a one-count for something does not score anything) and score for the others. So, test for two twos, and score that two.

If you score is this:

```
5 5 5 5 1
```

Then your first buckets are:

```
1 0 0 0 4
```

That's one one and four fives. So your second buckets are:

```
1 0 0 1 0
```

Your lookup table for this could be:

```
x 1 0 0 0 -> one pair
x 2 0 0 0 -> two pairs
x 0 1 0 0 -> three of a kind
x 1 1 0 0 -> full house
x 0 0 1 0 -> four of a kind
x 0 0 0 1 -> five of a kind
```

The 'x' means that you don't match on this. So, your lookup table matches four numbers to a score.

I was rather interested in this problem, so I have written some code to do the above. You'll still need to do the lookup table, but that is relatively trivial, and will be good practice for you. Here is a demo, with comments ([run code here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1wk-x0c)):

```
<?php
    function counting(array $array) {
        // Input figures
        print_r($array);

        // Run the figures twice through the bucket-counter
        $firstBuckets = bucketCounter($array);
        $secondBuckets = bucketCounter($firstBuckets);

        // Ignore counts of 1
        array_shift($secondBuckets);

        // Output, just need to do the lookup now
        echo ' converts to ';
        print_r($secondBuckets);
        echo "<br />";
    }

    /**
     * Bucket counter
     */
    function bucketCounter(array $array) {
        $result = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, );
        foreach($array as $value) {
            if ($value > 0) {
                $result[$value - 1]++;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    // Try some demos here!
    counting(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    counting(array(1, 1, 2, 4, 2));
    counting(array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1));

?>
```

The demos I've included seem to work, but do hunt for bugs!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I imagine I'm going to struggle to fight through this but thanks for educating me ! Sorry for being new to this, but when you say.. create a bucket. I'm lost.

Comment: Ah, okay: a bucket is just a Computer Science word for a storage index. So, where I say 'bucket', swap it for 'array' `:)`

Comment: Okay I'm understanding what you wrote pretty well, the problem I'm having is creating these arrays and scanning the users numbers to correspond to what you say. if 1,1,1,3,3 then that would = 3,0,2,0,0 in the array, and 1,2,3,4,5 would = 1,1,1,1,1 in the array. But how do I create these arrays to get the counts like you've showed me?

Comment: Thanks for the code update, this is pointing me in the right direction now! :D

Comment: Great. Be aware that on Stack Overflow, on most questions, people will ask for your code first, since the best way to learn is to try. Anyway there is the last little bit (the lookup table) for you to do, so I've not done everything. This bit is short enough that you could use a series of `if` statements, I reckon, but try a lookup array if you prefer!

Comment: 3, 2, 4, 1, 4 = Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 [3] => 1 [4] => 4 ) converts to Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 ) Does that equal correct? Just to make sure I've incorporated it correctly, then I'll get started on my lookup table !

Comment: Well, apply the algorithm to it manually, and you tell me `:)`. What's the value of that input set after applying just one bucket pass? (Understanding what the first and second iterations actually represent is the key to understanding what the algorithm is doing for you).

Comment: I've put the code in so my random numbers run through the process you've provided me with. and it equals exactly like you explained in the first half of your answer. I now just need to find the way to compare the result to score points to it. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote or accept (same goes for your other solved questions - it is how we say thanks on Stack Overflow)!

Comment: Hey again man, I'm looking everywhere to educate myself on lookup-tables for arrays but cannot find what I'm looking for :( is there any chance you could point me in the right direction? I'm sorry to be a pest.

Comment: Just use `if` statements, consulting the x-list I provided. For example, you could do `if ($result[0] == 2) { echo "You have two pairs"; }`. Add a whole bunch of `elseif`s to that, and you have a solution!

Comment: Thanks again my friend, you've helped me out a great deal ! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

Use array_count_value function for this.

```
$array = array(1,1,1,2,5);

print_r(array_count_values($array));

Array(
1 => 3,
2 => 1,
3 => 1
);
```

Comment: So would this count how many times 1 appeared in say 1,1,1,3,5 and give the score of 3? or if it showed 1,1,1,3,3 then it would score 5 for three of a kind and 2 of a kind?

Comment: This function just gives the number of times a value is getting repeated. If you want to calculate some score then you need to apply formula to its count.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand the part you've suggested after "Array(" if it did count that 1 appears 3 times, that would give me a score of 3? if the array you provided had 1,1,1,2,2 would it output 5 counts?

Answer (score 1):

If the range is quite small, you can use counting sort approach. For each number, provide a "bucket" to count how many times a number appear. Scan once to fill in the buckets. Then another scan, but this time against the bucket to get the highest value. That's your score.

Comment: dear downvoter, would you please explain rather than just downvote and leave? tell me what's wrong with my solution

Comment: Seems okay to me, +1. I agree that providing a full code solution is initially undesirable, until the OP shows us their attempt.

Comment: Ah, if you have an input of `1, 1, 2, 2, 4`, then the buckets approach gives: `1 => 2, 2 => 2, 4 => 1`. The score (according to the now modified question) should be 2, so I guess we could subtract 1 from all buckets if they are less than three (which they all are) and then sum them. Hence that looks like `1' => 1, 2' => 1, 4' => 0`. Summed, that is 2.

Comment: Oops, this falls apart for the pair in the full house! I think the buckets approach, plus a manual lookup table for the combinations, might be the best approach.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would set-up a "manual lookup table" and elaborate on what one is? thanks :)

Comment: Now after you updated the question, I would need to update a lot. I didn't understand the pair or full house rule before. But @halfer seems have given you that, so I won't change mine. The manual lookup table is also covered in his comments.